# How to support es6 in eclipse Photon

Tags: eclipse

I have JavaScript code that uses things like let, async, etc.  My eclipse Photon flags it as errors.  I installed WTP (SDK, Bundle, Dependencies, etc.).  It still does not recognize ES6.  Being a newbie to eclipse, getting the exact sequence to add ES6 support would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Blake McBride

Comment: Try the CodeMix plugin.

Comment: It's shocking to me that current eclipse can't support ES6.  intelliJ and NetBeans do.  How / why would anyone use eclipse to develop a web app?

Comment: eclipse is the platform. There are plugins to the platform which support ES6. I mentioned CodeMix but Webclipse also supports ES6. There are probably others but those are from the company I work for.